# error loadeRoutes() in laravel when enter php artisan serve

Tags: laravel-5.5, router

i when install myproject in server and enter (php artisan serve) in terminal
visit error bottom

> In Router.php line 393:
>   Illuminate\Routing\Router::loadRoutes(): Failed opening required '/home/adm   in/domains/vilanserver.com/public_html/routes/Api.php' (include_path='.:/us   r/local/lib/php')

help me please